# Assign and return select option dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form select which is generated based on results returned from a mysql query.

Q1) How do I assign a name identity (integer value) based on the teamID pull out of the database?

Q2) How could I then get the option selected and add it to a php variable which could then be used to update a table based on the users selection?

Below is the code I have so far for creating the dynamic drop down list, which get the results out of the database.

```
<?php 

                        $data= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams 
                                            WHERE teamID NOT IN (
                                                SELECT TeamID 
                                                FROM leagueInformation 
                                                WHERE leagueID = 1
                                                )

                      ") or die(mysql_query());

                        echo "<select name=\"team\" class=\"col-lg-12\" style=\"padding:10px; background:#e1e1e1;\">\n";  

                          while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
                          {

                            $teamID = $info['teamID'];

                            echo "<option name=" . $team . "  value=" . $teamID . ">" .$info['teamName'] . "</option>"; 


                          } 

                        echo "</select>\n";      
                      ?>
```

Comment: `name` is not a valid attribute for the `option` element.

Comment: When you say *How do I assign a name identity...*, assign to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Q1) How do I assign a name identity (integer value) based on the teamID pull out of the database?

This question is not so clear, but I think this is what you are trying to do?

```
<?php $data= mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE teamID NOT IN (
           SELECT TeamID 
           FROM leagueInformation 
           WHERE leagueID = 1)
    ") or die(mysql_query()); 
?>

<form name="teams_form" method="POST">
    <select name="team" class="col-lg-12" style="...">
        <?php while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )): ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $info['teamID'] ?>"> 
               <?php echo $info['teamName'] ?>
           </option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

#### Q2) How could I then get the option selected and add it to a php variable which could then be used to update a table based on the users selection?

First you will need to wrap your select inside a form (like I did), then you can check the selected value like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['team']) && !empty['team']){
   $selected_team =  $_POST['team'];
   mysql_query("Do what you want with the selected team");
}
```

#### Some notes about your code:

1. Avoid to use `mysql_*`, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`, and always prevent SQL injections
2. `<option>` tags don't have name properties, and in this case $team is not defined
3. Embed PHP inside HTML, not HTML in PHP.

Comment: in Bootstrap 3 col-lg-* classes are legit, you're talking about Boostrap 2.3.2

Comment: @ROLO: I'm not saying col-lg-* don't exist, but `col-lg-12` don't ;)

Comment: wrong, it exists and it is not equals to rows

http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css be my guest and search for it

Comment: @ROLO: You're right, edited... I read once that doesn't existed, but I see is for remove the negative margin of row.

Answer (score 0):

put everything in a `<form/>` with an action pointing to the page, and a method (get or post), then in the script get the variable by the `<select/`> name value reading `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables, and I quote the comment about the "name" in option as invalid attribute.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first question doesn't make sense to me yet, I'll update the answer when it does.
2. When the user submits the form, you can get the option selected using the `$_GET` or `$_POST` (depending your your form's `method`) variables.

Like this:

```
$teamId = $_POST['team'];
```